# Three "cannot be resolved to a variable" errors in Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maps, adt

In this part of my code I have three errors:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

- `context cannot be resolved`
- `latitude cannot be resolved to a variable`
- `longitude cannot be resolved to a variable`

I have tried with Ctrl+Shift+o to import those things ut it's not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where are you defining the variables latitude, longitude and context?

Comment: Eclipse never do these mistake. Programmers does. Ctrl+Schift+o imports, not define variables for you.

Comment: Throwing at us some error output and code snippets is not going to fix the problem at hand, buggy code, if the snippet is irrelevant and the error common and discussed.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-Shift-O only organises the `import` statements at the top of the file.

Your error is caused because you haven't declared fields or in-scope variables called `latitude`, `longitude` and `context`.

Depending upon the type of class you are working with, you may already have a suitable `Context` value being passed to your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As @Duncan wrote, you'll have to define variables in Java first, before you can use them.

Your code should look e.g. like this:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
String uri = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
this.startActivity(intent);
```

(Assuming you are calling this from an Activity)

You'll also have to add the following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

You can find more information on LocationManager [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Once you've changed your code, you will have the following imports to the beginning of your file:

```
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.content.Context;
```

These imports should also be suggested by Eclipse if you right-click on the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ill get now:
Context cannot be resolved to a variable
Location cannot be resolved to a type
LocationManager cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: OK, you'll now be able to import those, as they are Classes that need to be imported.

Comment: Okey thanks, i have placed all and now my app is stopped working on the device. In LogCat is only viewed a error called E and TID = -1

I have placed the code in the OnCreat. : public void onCreate

Comment: If your app crashed, you will also get a detailed error log in LogCat. You'll have to read a book or tutorials on Android development to get an understanding of the basics.

Comment: In logcat is only displaying: Device Disconnected. But in the Android launcher the error message says: Unfortunaley, App has stopped working.

Comment: Well, then you'll have to make sure your device is connected and your adb connection working. As mentioned above, you cannot ask questions for the most basic things. You'll have to extend your knowledge on Android. If you find your error log, you could open a new question for the new error.

Comment: Can i place your code in the public void OnCreate or must i made an new class?

Comment: Just add it to onCreate().